# Does the completion of an operator with closed image also have a closed image?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be real normed vector spaces, and suppose that $T:X \to Y$ is a bounded linear operator with **closed** image.

Let $\tilde X,\tilde Y$ be the completions of $X,Y$, and let $\tilde T:\tilde X \to \tilde Y$ be the natural continuous extension of $T$ (which is unique).

> Is $\text{Image } \tilde T$ closed in  $\tilde Y$?

I proved that  $\, \, \overline{\text{Image } \tilde T}^{\tilde Y}= \overline{\text{Image } T}^{\tilde Y} $, however, this doesn't seem to resolve the question. (We only know $\text{Image } T$ is closed in $Y$; it does not need to be closed in $\tilde Y$).

Comment: Indeed it is not true. Take $X$ to be Banach and $T':X\to X$ any map that does not have a closed image. Let $Y=\mathrm{im}(T')$ and $T$ the restriction of codomain of $T'$ to $Y$. Now $T$ has a closed image but if you change the codomain to the completion of $Y$ this is not true anymore.

Comment: Thanks! that seems to answer the question.